# C# Получить аудиодорожку из видео в чат телеграм бота

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Хочу получить аудио из видео.
Отправляю ссылку на видео - но не могу получить из него файл. Возможно решение где-то близко, но не могу до него догадаться.

```
    var video = await youtubeClient.Videos.GetAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1La4QzGeaaQ");
Console.WriteLine($"Название: {video.Title}");
Console.WriteLine($"Продолжительность: {video.Duration}");
Console.WriteLine($"Автор: {video.Author}");
    
var streamManifest = await youtubeClient.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1La4QzGeaaQ");


var streamInfo = (AudioOnlyStreamInfo)streamManifest.GetAudioOnlyStreams().GetWithHighestBitrate(); //тут получаю поток
       
bot.SendAudioAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, streamInfo.Url);
```

Comment: Сейчас проблема в чем? Чем код из вопроса не устроил?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в чат не приходит файл

Comment: А как телеграмм отправляет файлы? У всех одна ссылка или как? Если одна, то всеми этими манипуляциями, ютуб отдает ссылку персональную для вас, с вашим уникальным токеном и прочим, у других она действовать не должна. Тут наверно надо смотреть в сторону "сохранить у себя файл и дальше его передать", ютуб библиотека может дать вам `Stream`, который уже и пробуйте отправить (правда не знаю, позволяет ли телеграмм отправлять файл потоками/байтами). Но куда копать, думаю вы поняли.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ думал об этом , но не хотел у себя файлы сохранять. все равно спасибо!

Comment: А я не говорю про сохранение, я говорю про `Stream`, то есть прямая передача потока, без сохранения. Ну а про сохранение я вам лишь привел это в пример, чтоб было понятно, что ваш бот должен быть неким посредником, между ютуб и клиентом, ибо ссылка рабочая только для него. Но это сейчас лишь домыслы, не более. Пробуйте, изучайте, попробуйте знакомому дать ссылку что получаете, сможет воспроизвести? Также посмотрите, как и что именно отправляется телеграммом, ибо я им вообще не пользуюсь... Если ссылка одноразовая и телеграмм грузит по ней, то вот вам и проблема.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ охх, там все трудно. 

var streamInfo = (AudioOnlyStreamInfo)streamManifest.GetAudioOnlyStreams().GetWithHighestBitrate(); 
Тут получаю поток типа AudioOnlyStreamInfo от ютуба.

А телеграмм принимает поток типа IO.Stream. Видимо, сразу передать не получится. Костыли придется делать

Comment: А [это](https://telegrambots.github.io/book/3/files/upload.html)? `SendDocumentAsync` принимает `Steam`, который вы и получаете от библиотеки ютуба.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вроде работает, но файл не отправляет. Видимо косяк с потоком, который дает ссылку на файл. Там же не скачивание идет, а проигрывание файла. С ссылкой надо поработать, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я сделал это, черт побери! Вы натолкнули меня на мысли. Я пересмотрел библиотеку, взял пару строчек кода и все пошло как надо. Спасибо